# Getting error while storing data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make commenting system for my website but whenever I am submitting my data I am getting this error 
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Here is my code in web.php

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::resource('doomxos','DoomxosController');
```

here is the code in my model:-

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Doomxo extends Model
{
//
 public function userd(){

return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
}
```

here is the code in  my blade file

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
<div class="row new-post">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

        <header><h3>comments</h3></header>
        <form action="route('doomxos.store')" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="new-post"    rows="5" placeholder="Your comment "></textarea>
            </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post comment</button>

        </form>
     </div>
    </div>

 @foreach($doomxos as $doomxo)
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

```
 {{$doomxo->created_at}}

 {{$doomxo->body }}


@endforeach


 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
 <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
 <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is my code in controller:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Doomxo;
use Auth;
use App\User;

class DoomxosController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    // 
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
$doomxos = doomxo::all();
return view('doomxos.create', ['doomxos' => $doomxos]);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //

 $doomxo= new Doomxo();
    $doomxo->user_id=Auth::userd()->id;
    $doomxo->body=$request->body;
    $request->userd()->doomxos()->save($doomxo);
    return back();
 }

 /**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function show($id)
 {
    //
    $doomxos=doomxo::all();
 return view('doomxos',['doomxos'=>$doomxos]);
 }

 /**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function edit($id)
 {
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

Here is the cone in my user.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
 ];

public function comments() {


return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');

}
public function doomxos() {


return $this->hasMany('App\Doomxo');

}

}
```

Thanks in advance:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form action isn't correct, you have:

```
<form action="route('doomxos.store')" method="post">
```

You need to use the curly braces as this is a function that needs to run:

```
<form action="{{ route('doomxos.store') }}" method="post">
```